# Pentaho script invocation not working properly

Tags: powershell, pentaho

I'm running a PowerShell script from pentaho, but I encounter the following problem. When it is called, the script step gets as parameter the rows that are processed by the previous step. From the images should be more clear what is the problem.

[image]

This is the complete transformation.

[image]

This is how the steps are configured.

[image]

Here are the parameters of the transformation before the script step.

[image]

This is the result after the execution. The string after the `....shell.bat` contains the names of the rows that were processed by the previous step. If I do no process any row this string is not present. The problem is that this string should not be passed as parameter to the `powershell.exe` command, the first parameter should be the path to the script file. In fact in the row below (the output) the command is correct.

The problem is that I looked all the options and controlled all the variables, and seem everything ok. I'm not able to run the command successfully because I cannot remove this passed parameter (which I don't pass, but pentaho pass it by itself).

It is possible that is a bug or something? Can anyone give me some indications on how to solve this. Thank you.

Comment: For now I managed to solve by inserting a dummy transformation right before the script step, and choosing the options "Clear results rows before execution" and "Clear results files before execution". The options are available by doing double-click on the dummy transformation step. But this is only a workaround. I think the problem is that in a step before the script step, I do a "copy rows to result" step, which copy the filename in the memory. So I think what happens is that the file names remain in memory and are erroneously passed as parameter to the script step.